# using git to compare one file from two commits

Tags: git, debugging, git-diff

I have a file that has broken somewhere down the line, and I have found the last point in which it was still fixed.

I would like to know how, using git, I can compare one file from two commits, or indeed if that is the best way to play this!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To directly answer your question, suppose you want to compare the file `src/toaster.c` between your current `master` and the old commit `f4l4f3l`, you can just do:

```
git diff master f4l4f3l -- src/toaster.c
```

As an alternative, you can just look through all the changes to that file with:

```
git log -p -- src/toaster.c
```

---

More generally, however, if you're trying to find the commit where a particular bug was introduced, git has a marvellous tool for this, called [git bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html).  If you tell this tool a working and non-working commit, it will give you a series of commits to test in between those, using a binary search strategy.

You would start bisecting with the command:

```
git bisect start
```

Then if your current commit has the bug, you just do:

```
git bisect bad
```

Next, you need to find an older commit that definitely didn't have the bug.  This might have a particular tag, or perhaps you'll just pick a commit that was some months ago.  Suppose that one is called `a12b3d`, then you would do:

```
git checkout a12b3d
git bisect good
```

At that point, git will work out the next commit you'll need to test, and do `git checkout` to move you to that commit.  (These checkouts will all be with "detached HEAD", so your original branch pointer is unchanged.)  You then test that commit, and run `git bisect good` or `git bisect bad` depending on whether it has the bug or not.  This binary search between the revisions will quickly narrow down to the first bad commit, and report which one it is.  Then to go back to what you were doing, you can do:

```
git bisect reset
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but before I start, should I not use 'bisect good' after finding the the commit that doesn't have the bug?

Comment: Oops, yes - that should have been `git checkout a12b3d; git bisect good`.  I've corrected that typo in the answer now.

Comment: Okay, so I have found my bad commit, and I can see what is wrong. What is the best way now to change that and pull it forward?

Comment: Okay, so I looked at the last good commit, saw the issue, went to the first bad commit and fixed it, I then cherry-picked that commit into the required branch. In hindsight, I might as well have just switched to the current version and fixed it direct.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: yes, once you've identified the bug, the easiest way to fix it is just to commit a fix at the tip of your branch.  However, you've got lots of options then - e.g. if the bad commit has nothing good in it, you could just use `git revert`; if you've not made this history public, you could fix that commit during an interactive rebase; etc. etc.

Answer (score 4):

```bash
git diff $start_commit..$end_commit -- path/to/file
```

For instance, you see the difference for a file `file.c` between now and two commits back

```bash
git diff HEAD^^..HEAD -- file.c
```